# Google contacts API - Contact name not sync with goolge+

Tags: google-contacts-api

I'm using google contact API v3 to get list of contacts but contact name always empty. (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#contacts-query-parameters-reference)

In Gmail, when i send email to a gmail address which linkage to google plus and wait for a few hours then i can search that address included name same as google+ but google contact api still response an empty name.

Anyone tell me how to search contacts as Gmail?

Comment: You need to post us the code you currently have.

Comment: I send a get request to https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&q="email_address"
 
You can test it on https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
 Step 1: Select Contacts v3 and login
 Step 2: Click on "Exchange authorization code for tokens" button
 Step 3: Select "List contacts" API and try.